# Cross-referencing in eplain

Tags: cross-referencing, eplain

I have written a math textbook, and a solutions manual to accompany it.  In the solutions manual, I would like to refer to equation numbers in the textbook.  How do I do this in eplain tex?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Do you have defined automatic numbering for equations? Anyway, this is explained in section 4.11 of the manual.